# How one can limit a user to a specific network namespace?

Tags: networking, authentication, namespace

Suppose I have a Linux host with a few non-default network namespaces. I need to limit a specific user to a specific network namespace based on the results of user authentication. For example:

- user1 with his password or an ssh key authenticates to the Linux host and gets into network namespace ns1
- user2 with his password or an ssh key authenticates to the Linux host and gets into network namespace ns2

In other words, I need to isolate users into different network namespaces based on the results of authentication, i.e., based on the information of "who is who". Both users must see only the routes they are authorized to see.

Comment: https://github.com/rd235/libpam-net (see also http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_namespace.html)